# Are all exceptions throw from Jdbi of type JdbiException?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

It states here:

https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/JdbiException.html

that `JdbiException` is the `Base unchecked exception for exceptions thrown from jdbi.`

However, if I'm calling the `withHandle` method with various different callbacks:

```
jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
            .createQuery("...")
            .mapTo(String.class)
            .one());
```

the docs state that it throws `X extends Exception` (rather than throwing `JdbiExecption` as I would have expected) and describes it as `@param <X> exception type thrown by the callback, if any.`:

```
public <R, X extends Exception> R withHandle(HandleCallback<R, X> callback) throws X {
```

I want to know if it is safe to do call `withHandle` and just catch `JdbiException`, rather than having to catch `Exception`?

```
try {
  jdbi.withHandle(handle -> ...);
} catch (JdbiException e) {
    // Will this catch everything thrown from `withHandle`?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of that `X extends Exception` is for **your** code, not JDBI's code. The code you *write yourself* (after the `->`) can throw `X`.

JDBI will indeed be throwing JdbiExceptions, and won't be throwing anything else. But *YOUR CODE* might e.g. throw IOException or whatnot.

This works:

```
try {
  jdbi.withHandle(handle -> throw new IOException());
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

and to make that work, that's what the `<X extends Exception>` is all about.

Comment: Thanks, so if *my code* is always code that is calling some JDBI method, such `handle -> handle().createQuery(...).mapTo(...).one()` or `handle -> handle.createUpdate(...).execute()`, then I can assume that only JdbiExceptions will be thrown?

Comment: Yup. you got it :)